# sharedViewModel, how to access from Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, viewmodel

I have a problem with my Fragment and ViewModel.
This is the code in my Fragment:

```
       private val sharedViewModel: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        alarm.setOnClickListener {
            sharedViewModel.alarmState.value = AlarmState.Activated
        }

        sharedViewModel.alarmState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,  {   Observer<AlarmState> {
            when(it){
               AlarmState.Activated -> {
                   text_alarm.text = "Alarmanlage aktiviert"
                   alarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_image_red);
                   alarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarmanlage_an)
               }
               AlarmState.GetsActivated ->{
                   text_alarm.text = "Alarmanlage wird aktiviert"
                   alarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_image_orange);
                   alarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarmanlage_aus)
               }
               AlarmState.Deactivated ->{
                   text_alarm.text = "Alarmanlage aus"
                   alarm.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_image_green);
                   alarm.setImageResource(R.drawable.alarmanlage_aus)
               }
           }
           }
          })
```

and this is my ViewModel

```
class SharedViewModel:ViewModel(){
    var alarmState: MutableLiveData<AlarmState> = MutableLiveData<AlarmState>(Deactivated)
 }
```

so the AlarmState is initally deactivated.

clicking on 'alarm' sets the State to Activated.

Shouldn't now AlarmState-observer firing and executing?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show how `AlarmState` is implemented?

Comment: remove extra `Observer<AlarmState> { }`, it should be `sharedViewModel.alarmState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { code }) ` or `sharedViewModel.alarmState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { code }` which is the same

Comment: Thanks a lot IR42, removing Observer<AlarmState> did fix it!